# How to detect Push notification when app is open

Tags: ios, push-notification

In my application i have used push notification service but my problem is that when i close the app at that time the notification appears but when i open the application and then send the notification the notification not come. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can **easily handle by this function mentioned below** in your `appDelegate.m`

---implement `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

**Example:-**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{

    UIApplicationState appState = [application applicationState];
    if (appState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {

            UIAlertView *alertVw = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notify" message:yourMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles: @"vizllx", nil] autorelease];

            [alertVw show];
    }
    else {
        // Push Notification received while app is in background
    }
}
```